# What happens when using pass by reference and member initialization lists in C++ classes?

Tags: c++, class

Okay, so I have a large vector say

```
vector<vector<vector<int>>>
```

of 10000 by 10000 by 10000.

I have a class which has  such a vector as a private member variable:

```
class foo {
private:
vector<vector<vector<int>>> myvector
};
```

I have a constructor for my class that uses pass by reference and initializer list:

```
foo(vector<vector<vector<int>>> &myvector_in) : myvector(myvector_in);
```

I want to know what's exactly happening in terms of memory usage. Is the private myvector the same as the one that was originally declared, or is it a copy.

Basically, I want to know if there are ever two version of myvector in memory.

Thank You!

Comment: Aside: `foo(const vector<vector<vector<int>>> &myvector_in)` would be better.

Comment: *"Basically, I want to know if there are ever two version of myvector in memory."* - Yes, there will always be two copies when you construct a `foo` object with that constructor, because the member initializer made a copy

Comment: The vector in the class is different fromthe vector in the caller. But there's no intermediate copy -- a reference is really just a pointer behind the scenes.

Comment: If you have a `vector` taking up 4 TB, I don't think you need us to tell you whether there are ever two copies in memory...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a member of type `vector<vector<vector<int>>>` and initialize it with another `vector<vector<vector<int>>>`. How would it be possible not to have said data twice in memory? Thats more a matter of logic than a matter of c++.

#### Alternatives

You could store a pointer `vector<vector<vector<int>>>*` or a reference `vector<vector<vector<int>>>&` to the vector in an appropriate class member. Or use one of the smart pointers to do so. In any of these cases some serious thinking about memory management is a good idea.

Or you use a move constructor, which is moving the passed in vector in your member vector.

```
using vec = std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>;

class foo {
public:
    foo() = delete;
    foo(const vec&) = delete;
    foo(vec&& myvector_in) : myvector(std::move(myvector_in)) {};
private:
    vec myvector;
};
```

Of course that will render that argument passed to the constructor useless but that a trivial consequence of the not-copying you want.

You can pass your vector to that constructor if you first cast it to an rvalue using std::move:

```
foo my_foo(std::move(test));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fishing tip.

Fairly easy to answer yourself. Set [0][0][0] of myvector_in to a known value. Invoke the constructor and inside it also set [0][0][0] but of myvector to a different value. Once the constructor has returned, print the content of myvector_in. If it's the same as the one you original set you must conclude that the two vectors are different entities, thus one was copied into a different one.  If they are the same than you can conclude they are in fact the same instances.

You could also print addresses to get a better sense of what's what.

I must point out, the memory requirement mention in your original question are in the realm of super computer, you got one?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way of addressing this issue in C++11 (and newer) is to accept the constructor argument **by value**:

```
struct foo {
  using vec=std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>;  // from DrSvanHay
  foo(vec v) : myvector(std::move(v)) {}
private:
  vec myvector;
};
```

Surprisingly, this actually minimizes copies:

1. If the client has a `vector cv;`, `cv` gets copied into the parameter `v`, but that copy was necessary to have `cv` and `foo::myvector` upon completion.
2. If the client passes `std::move(cv)`, `cv` gets moved into `v` and there is no copy.
3. If the client passes `make_vector(...)`, the parameter `v` is move-initialized from the return value (or, in C++17, [is the return value](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)).

(In all these cases, `v` is then moved into `foo::myvector`, of course.)